# Tail a file efficiently in nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs, tail

I am creating an application which would watch a file and fetch the contents  from that file (similar to tail but with the possibility of paging in previous data as well). I read up on quite a few solutions ranging from spawning a new process to getting only the updated bytes of the file but I am still a little confused on a few parts.

What I want to do exactly is the following:

- Watch a file and trigger an event/callback whenever new data comes into the file
- Read this new data from the file and efficiently send it to a client. Using a websocket or something else. (suggest a good way to do this please)
- At the client end, take this data and display it to user and keep updating it with new data as it comes
- If the user requests older data a way to fetch that data from the file we are watching

I am looking for efficient solutions for the above sub problems and any suggestions for a better approach are also welcome.

FYI I am new to nodejs so verbosity in your solutions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

#### Watch for changes

Suggest you look at [chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar), it is an optimized implementation of fs.watch, fs.events, the native node.js libraries.

```
// Initialize watcher.
const watcher = chokidar.watch('some/directory/**/*.xml', config);

// Add event listeners.
watcher
  .on('add', path => log(`File ${path} has been added`))
  .on('change', path => log(`File ${path} has been changed`))
  .on('unlink', path => log(`File ${path} has been removed`));
```

#### To get the changed value

Here you can look at [diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff) module. And you will need to store the state of the previous and current files. In order to build the changes.

#### To notify the client

You will need to create a websocket server, recommend you to use [socket.io](https://socket.io/) and then in your application you will create the diff and send a websocket message to the server. The server will notify/broadcast the message to the needed clients.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Kindly also suggest on how to fetch this changed data from the File as well as a good way to send that data over to the client.

Comment: @amaze-name Updated the answer.

Comment: the diff module is great but if I have to calc diff of new additions to a file then either i would either have to keep the copy of the prev file or store its content somewhere before checking the diff. The issue is that the file I am checking the new content for can be huge and I don't want the node app to hog too much resources.

Comment: An idea can be to use a versioning system, that stores only the patches from one version to other. Something to give you only what is new, is impossible, because you came with the assumption that your file will be only appended, but if the file is modified, or lines are removed then what the difference will be ?